# How to reference element from [NSObject : AnyObject] Swift dictionary after bridging from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In our Swift app, we are having trouble invoking an Objective-C library. The goal is to reference an element from a dictionary that has been converted from a `NSDictionary` through a bridging header.

Objective-C function signature:

```
vision (PBJVision *)vision capturedVideo:(nullable NSDictionary *)videoDict error:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

Swift conversion:

```
func vision(vision: PBJVision, capturedVideo videoDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)
```

We want the following equivalent in Swift:

```
outputPath = [videoDict  objectForKey:PBJVisionVideoPathKey];
```

We tried `videoDict["PBJVisionVideoPathKey"]` and `videoDict[PBJVisionVideoPathKey]`, and Google references haven't turned anything up for how to reference dictionary elements when NSObjects are the key. The error Xcode gives is `Could not find overload for "subscript" that accepts the supplied arguments.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant approach, but this worked:

```
    let castedVideoDict = videoDict as! Dictionary<String, NSObject>        
    let filePath = castedVideoDict["PBJVisionVideoPathKey"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you want

```
let outputPath = videoDict[PBJVisionVideoPathKey]
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Yes, we have tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: And what was the error message. Kind of hard to figure out what is wrong if you don't say...

Answer (score 0):

The key is PBJVisionVideoPathKey, not "objectForKey:PBJVisionVideoPathKey"

```
videoDict[PBJVisionVideoPathKey]
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Yes, we have tried that, but it didn't work.